# Why does assignment on a non-subsetted series overwrite the entire series but assignment on a df-subsetted series overwrites by-value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset, series

I was completing an exercise on string substitution within a df.

I'll simply the code to illustrate the point

```
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'column1':['a','a','b','b']})
```

Say I want to change every 'b' to an 'a'. My initial inclination was to use .str.replace(), which could work. But I noticed an example elsewhere (without explanation) that I could instead just write:

```
test2.loc[test2['column1'] == 'b', 'column1'] = 'a'
```

which returns a series of all a's.

This was a bit curious to me because if I take the type of

```
test2.loc[test2['column1'] == 'b', 'column1']
```

I get <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

But if I were to create an identical starter-series from scratch:

```
test1 = pd.Series(['a','a','b','b'])
```

I get the same object type. Yet if I write

```
test1 = 'a'
```

that would convert the entire series object into the one-letter string, 'a'.

I know that a workaround could be to subset the non-subsetted series itself, i.e.,

```
test1[test1 == 'b'] = 'a'
```

which yields the same 4-element series of 'a'.

But I don't totally follow the technical reason for when/why you can simply assign a value to a series and have it replace respective values in the series, instead of overwrite the series altogether. So clarification on this specific point would be appreciated!

Comment: *"When you can simply assign a value to a series and have it replace respective values in the series?"* Never.

Comment: `test2.loc[test2['column1'] == 'b', 'column1']` is a series, but it's comming`test2`. so when you do just `test2.loc[test2['column1'] == 'b', 'column1']`, Python calls `test_2.__getitem()`, but when you do`test2.loc[test2['column1'] == 'b', 'column1'] = 'a'`, Python actually calls `test2.__setitem__()` or something similar. That's how Pandas is designed. On the other hand, `test2 = 'a'` (without the square bracket) for example, you would replace the entire dataframe. This is similar to working on a list.

Comment: @MechanicPig the correct syntax would be `test1[:] = 'a'`.

Comment: @QuangHoang Is this a *simple* assignment?

Comment: Thanks! Please correct me if I'm wrong but my takeaway for assignment/subsetting here is that, if you assign X to a subsetted df/series, X will become the value of each respective element of that subset (even if the subset was itself the entire range); whereas if you assign X to a non-subsetted df/series, X will replace the df/series as the sole value of the new object